# Adding actions to Capistrano tasks

Tags: capistrano

How can I add something to Capistrano's deploy task? I need to create a symlink in "public" directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new task to create the symlink, then use a hook to add your task into the Capistrano deploy workflow where appropriate.

e.g.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "symlink my file"
  task :symlink_file, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -s file public/file"
  end
end

after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:symlink_file'
```